# « tirer les marrons du feu »: Does one do the dirty work, being unaware of the manipulation at work? Is it the same as 火中の栗を拾う in Japanese?

Tags: expressions, japonais

Une francophone vient de me faire savoir que l’expression japonaise 火中の栗を拾う provient de « tirer les marrons du feu » qui tire son origine de l’une des fables de La Fontaine.

En japonais, 火中の栗を拾う signifie qu’un chat, se montrant sensible à la flatterie habile d’un singe, fini par jouer les marionnettes et faire tout le sale boulot rien que pour ce dernier, en courant de grands risques pour lui prendre des marrons brûlants — et ce ***sans se rendre compte*** d’être victime d'une manipulation psy.

Quant à « tirer les marrons du feu », je me demande si on se porte volontaire, ***en connaissance de cause ou non***, au gré des intérêts de celui qui ne cherche qu'à profiter de sa gentillesse ?

Answer (score 5):

Ni l'un ni l'autre. On ne tire les marrons du feu ni sans s'en rendre compte, ni volontairement pour l'intérêt d'un tiers. Le sens original et habituel de cette expression n'est donc pas l'un de ceux décrits dans la question.

On dit de quelqu'un qu'il **tire les marrons du feux** quand il tire opportunément profit de quelque chose au bon moment, souvent aux dépens de quelqu'un d'autre qui l'aurait plus mérité.

C'est donc le singe Bertrand de la fable qui tire les marrons du feu avec la patte du chat Raton, à l'inverse de l'expression japonaise où c'est le chat qui tire les marrons du feu.

L'expression est plus ancienne que cette fable de 1678. Elle est attestée dans l'ouvrage *Curiositez françoises*, Antoine Oudin, 1640 où la personne qui tire les marrons du feu le fait bien aux dépens d'un tiers:

[image]

On retrouve aussi l'utilisation opportuniste d'un tiers par celui qui tire les marrons du feu dans *Propos rustiques ; baliverneries; contes et discours d'Eutrapel* par Noël du Fail 1610 :

> Me souvenant des grands princes qui gagent la vie de cinquante mille hommes, où ils ne couchent rien du leur, ressemblant au singe qui tire les châtaignes de sous la braise avec la patte du lévrier endormi au foyer.

Quand à savoir si l'intermédiaire est volontaire ou non, les exemples montrent que les deux cas sont possibles: le lévrier qui dort n'est pas conscient de ce que le singe fait avec sa patte, le chat le fait volontairement suite à la flatterie du singe, les soldats prennent des risques en étant au service du prince qui lui n'en prend aucun.

Aujourd'hui, l'expression est souvent employée alors qu'il n'y a pas d'intermédiaire. Celui qui tire les marrons du feu est dans ce cas aussi celui-qui prend les marrons dans la braise. L'idée de profit plus ou moins immérité est cependant toujours sous entendue.

Answer (score -1):

A l'origine **tirer les marrons du feu** signifie clairement faire quelque chose de dangereux uniquement au profit de quelqu'un d'autre. Le sens a depuis évolué par inversion.
Rien n'indique si la personne qui "tire les marrons du feu" fait quelque chose de dangereux en connaissance de cause ou non, cela dépend du contexte.